# Why can't I use pushed History.state property set in a fetch API function?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function call API using fetch() function and then push received json to History.state using history.pushState(json). I need to use the state property afterwards but when I test console.log(history.state) right after that function, it printed null

What I tried:

```
function1();
function2();

function function1() {
  const request = new Request('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
  fetch(request)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(
    json => 
    {
      history.pushState(json,'','');
      console.log(history.state)
    }
  );
}

function function2() {
  console.log(history.state);
}
```

I even tried to wait util history.state not null using while loop (because I think it can be the order problem) but it didn't work. I want to print out exactly what I push to history.state before, this is what actually resulted:

```
null
// [object Object] 
{
  "page": 2,
  "per_page": 6,
  "total": 12,
...
```

This is a demo of the problem on codepen:
https://codepen.io/L-Ph-t-the-scripter/pen/PoaeqzJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the problem because function1 is async. So you should wait for its response and then running function2.

For this you have 2 options. First is to use async/await function like this:

```js
function async runFunctions() {
  await function1();
  function2();
}

runFunctions();

function async function1() {
  const request = new Request('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
  await fetch(request)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(
    json => 
    {
      history.pushState(json,'','');
      console.log(history.state)
    }
  );
}

function function2() {
  console.log(history.state);
}
```

And second way is to call function2 after getting function1 response:

```js
function1();

function async function1() {
  const request = new Request('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
  fetch(request)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(
    json => 
    {
      history.pushState(json,'','');
      console.log(history.state);
      function2();
    }
  );
}

function function2() {
  console.log(history.state);
}
```

Read more about async/await [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I used it successfully. But the answer should be include await before fetch function for the idea to work.

Answer (score 0):

`function1` uses promises, so `function2` is called to early.
Try putting `function2` right after the `history.pushState` call.

```js
function1();

function function1() {
  const request = new Request('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
  fetch(request)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(
    json => 
    {
      history.pushState(json,'','');
      function2();
      console.log(history.state)
    }
  );
}

function function2() {
  console.log(history.state);
}
```

Basically, `.then` waits for it (the request) to finish but continues running other code while waiting, making `function2` run before `function1` is finished.

I would recommend reading [this](https://medium.com/jspoint/javascript-promises-and-async-await-as-fast-as-possible-d7c8c8ff0abc#:%7E:text=Using%20promises%2C%20we%20can%20write,time%20and%20code%20becomes%20scalable.&text=JavaScript%20executes%20code%20in%20a%20single%20thread%2C%20which%20makes%20it%20blocking.) or [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises).